# Why can i still not ask questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I have been active on both Serverfault and Stackoverflow for a couple years, in the beginning just like most new users I asked some bad questions mostly styling and lazy formatting.

It wasn't long before I was unable to ask questions. I read the how to get off the naughty list articles. After bring my rep up to ~150 editing the bad questions I was still on the naughty list and after a couple months I gave up.

On serverfault I can ask question no problem, stackoverflow I have been banned for years and cannot figure out what to do to get off the naught list.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot answer for Stack Overflow, but here on Server Fault, you are not banned.